# Get Value from Previous Row

Tags: plsql

I'm trying to get the value from a previous row and then add this onto the value in a current row for reporting purposes.

The purpose of the report is to see the total orders in a day made before 5PM and shipped out before 10PM, 
any orders which were ordered after 5PM need to be added to the next day, but also any orders which didn't meet the before 5PM before 10PM criteria are also added to the total for the next day.

```
SELECT SUB1."DATE",
  COUNT(SUB1."ORDER_ID")                   AS "TOTAL",
  SUM(SUB1."SAME_DAY")                     AS "SAME_DAY",
  (COUNT(SUB1."ORDER_ID") - SUM(SUB1.SAME_DAY)) AS "CARRIED_FORWARD",
  SUM(SUB1."AFTER_5"),
  SUM(SUB1."AFTER_5_CF"),
  SUM(SUB1."SAME_DAY1_CF")
FROM
  (SELECT TO_CHAR(ORDER_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS "DATE",
    ORDER_ID,
    CASE
      WHEN TO_CHAR(ORDER_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') = TO_CHAR(SHIPPED_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY')
      AND TO_CHAR(ORDER_DATE, 'HH24')        < 17
      AND TO_CHAR(SHIPPED_DATE, 'HH24')      < 22
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END AS "SAME_DAY",
    CASE
      WHEN TO_CHAR(ORDER_DATE, 'HH24') >= 17
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END AS "AFTER_5",
    CASE
      WHEN TO_CHAR(ORDER_DATE , 'DD-MM-YYYY') = TO_CHAR(SHIPPED_DATE - 1, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
      AND TO_CHAR(ORDER_DATE , 'HH24')        >= 17
      AND TO_CHAR(SHIPPED_DATE, 'HH24')       < 22
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END AS "AFTER_5_CF",
    CASE
      WHEN TO_CHAR(ORDER_DATE , 'DD-MM-YYYY') = TO_CHAR(SHIPPED_DATE - 1, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
      AND TO_CHAR(ORDER_DATE , 'HH24')        < 17
      AND TO_CHAR(SHIPPED_DATE, 'HH24')       < 22
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END AS "SAME_DAY1_CF"
  FROM ORDER_HEADER
  WHERE ORDER_DATE BETWEEN TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-11-07', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-11-13', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  )SUB1
GROUP BY SUB1."DATE"
```

The above code gives me everything I need, but total should be (total + carried forward + after 5) and "Same Day" should be (Same Day + After 5 CF + Same Day 1 CF)

I've tried making use of LAG to give it the previous date, but I was unsure if I was using this correctly, if there isn't a way to do this and show the information on a single line then that is fine.

If I can get this working then I should be able to handle Friday,Saturdays and Sundays as for them their carried forwards need to be added to the Monday after.

Comment: `LAG` is indeed what you're after. Please edit your question to add in sample data and the expected output you're trying to get to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need a window clause to dynamically look back a certain number of rows. The syntax is along the lines of:

```
SUM(some_col) over ( order by col range between nn preceding and nn following)
```

which lets the current row "look" back or forward based on the size of a certain range (eg look back 3 days and look forward 1 day etc).  In your case, you want to dynamically change that amount based on the current data, ie, most days we look back one day, but for Monday, we want to look back over the weekend as well.

You can achieve that with a function call to control that within the window clause. Coincidentally, I did a tutorial covering *exactly* that scenario as part of an window function SQL series. You can that demo here

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y40v2Rwqs4Q&list=PLJMaoEWvHwFIUwMrF4HLnRksF0H8DHGtt&index=16

Comment: I have a working solution without doing this, but it includes what I can only describe as funky sql. Once I have more time I will look into implementing your solution as it will be a lot easier to manage.